# Delphi - Fazer uma Thread que toque uma música em loop

Tags: delphi, thread, loop, embarcadero, delphi-xe8

Eu consegui fazer uma Thread que toque a música, mas apenas por 1 vez.
 Se eu colocar um laço nela tenho diversos errors, como o 1400.

Parece que a thread não fecha quando se fecha o Form1, pois o problema sempre dá quando eu tento fecha-lo.

Eu tenho apenas 2 units. 1 é o Form1 e a outra é a TMusica thread.

Já tentei o Goto, While, Repeat, With. Nada funciona, a música se chama music.mp3. Uso o `Delphi XE8`. Como resolvo?

**Chamada da Thread TMusica:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
var
  Thread:TMusica;
begin
   //Bloco de Códigos
  Thread := TMusica.Create(False);  
  Thread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Thread.Resume;
   //Outros códigos...
 end;
```

**A Thread TMusica:**

```
procedure TMusica.Execute; 
begin 
  Form1.MediaPlayer1.FileName: = 'music.mp3';
  Form1.MediaPlayer1.Open;
  Form1.MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

Comment: Posta ai um pedaço do código que toca a musica! Pra te ajudar precisamos ver o que o código, não da pra ficar chutando e chutando!

Comment: Segue o meu projeto. É super pequeno, Obrigado por ajudar. http://www.mediafire.com/download/d6dqwba74ijodxx/Projects.zip

Comment: @VictorDm coloque o código relevante a pergunta em vez de colocar um *link*. Dessa forma, fica mais fácil ajuda-lo. Neste caso diria para colocar o código relevante a *thread* do som

Answer (score 5):

Bom, analisei seu projeto e você não precisa fazer tudo aquilo para funcionar, basta seguir os procedimentos simples a seguir:

Adicione no formulário um componente `TMediaPlayer` e mude a propriedade `Visible` dele para False;

No evento OnCreate do formulário adicione estes procedimentos:

```
procedure frmExemplo.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.Close;
  MediaPlayer1.FileName:=('d:\01.mp3'); //Caminho do seu arquivo Mp3
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

Adicione um componente `TTimer`, altere a propriedade `Interval` dele para `84000` (84000 corresponde a 1 minuto e 24 segundos em Milissegundos), ou seja, quando exatamente a musica terminar ela voltara a tocar:

```
procedure frmExemplo.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

Os dois componente que mencionei estão na Aba `System`.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!!

Comment: Se deu certo, foi útil, marque a resposta como Correta para que facilite para os demais encontrar as soluções!